# How can I change the status of the site? - PHP

Tags: php, status, http-response-codes

I am a novice and I work in PHP.
My English is not very good. If you see a typo, please edit it.

I need a function that changes the status of the site. Like the following function:

```
var_dump(http_response_code()); // return 200

function changeStatus($from, $to) {
    // The code I need
}
changeStatus(200, 404);

var_dump(http_response_code()); // return 404
```

Is such a thing possible at all?
please guide me

Comment: Take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

Comment: Yes, I checked. But I need a function to change the status of the site

Comment: that is literally what http-response-code does http_response_code(404) will set the code to 404 for example

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but it does not work.`var_dump(http_response_code(404));`

Comment: The documentation page says `If response_code is provided, then the **previous** status code will be returned`, so that means var_dumping the return value from the call which sets the value isn't a valid test. You can always check the response code using your browser's developer tools, or make a second call to the function e.g. `http_response_code(404); var_dump(http_response_code());`

Comment: @mordad Hi, check  my answer and mark it accepted if resolves your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong because it returns the previous result

```
var_dump(http_response_code(404)); // return 200
```

**Try this. This answer is safer**

```
function changeStatus($responseCode)
{
    if (http_response_code($responseCode))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
changeStatus(404);
```

Answer (score 3):

This code will solve your problem

```
function changeStatus($response_code) {
    // The code I need
    http_response_code($response_code);
}
changeStatus(404);

var_dump(http_response_code());
```

Comment: I am the author of the question. This is the correct answer. Please explain a little

Comment: when response code is passed to http_response_code then it sets code of page and returns previous response code when you call this function without parameter then it returns the response code of page